# Laser Turn-on delay

Tags: optoelectronics

When switching a laser diode, the turn on delay depends strongly on the initial bias current in the off state. This affects the duty cycle when attempting to generate a square wave. It also can produce strong data-dependent jitter when the laser is used to transmit an OOK data signal with a high extinction ratio.

I would like to ask if someone can explain in a simple way why the turn on delay on a laser reduces by increasing the bias current on it.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: I actually think this is a very basic question in relation to having more light generation. Can you be a bit more detailed about your application, ie. Laser type?

Comment: @Kortuk, "bias current" doesn't really make sense for any kind of laser other than a diode laser; and the issue is universal to any kind (visible, IR, Fabry-Perot, VCSEL, whatever) of diode laser.

Comment: @ThePhoton, our gain medium when I built a laser would cause your turn on to be much faster if you were to drive it harder as it could fold back and start lasing due to the presence of more light. Forgive me, you, as the photon, probably know more then I do. My point still stands, this question may be poorly worded, but it is an understandable question for someone in the field, albeit a tiny bit lackluster.

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm not so much familiar with gas lasers -- I guess the pump source an electric discharge, which does actually carry a current. But do you normally consider the bias point to be defined in terms of a voltage or a current? And do you normally worry so much about how long they take to turn on? ... On the other hand, the point of the question may only have been obvious to me because I spent too much time in grad school figuring out the answer to it.

Comment: @ThePhoton, You may have missunderstood me, I was not challenging your understanding of the question, I was saying you know better then myself. I am not a big photonics guy, my wife holds that role and I only have taken one Lasers class where we built one with a gain medium and such. I did not know enough to be sure it was a solid state based laser, but I assumed it was. If you edit the question to expand to what you think the user is actually meaning to ask you might help the OP word what they do not yet know the proper language for.

Answer (score 3):

As in any oscillator, the fundamental condition for a laser to lase is for the round trip gain to equal the losses. For a laser this means that as the optical wave makes a round trip through the cavity formed by two mirrors, the gain from the excited medium must equal the losses from imperfect mirror reflection, diffraction, etc.

For a diode laser, the gain is roughly proportional to the carrier (electrons and holes) density in the cavity.

So, to turn on the laser, you need to raise the carrier density until it provides enough gain to overcome the cavity's optical losses. Because the gain region is storing charge, electrically it has the behavior of a capacitor, and when the capacitor is charged to a certain level, the laser will begin to lase. But also, the carriers are constantly recombining through different mechanisms so a certain current is needed to maintain a given charge. This means that below threshold the laser's electrical behavior is essentially like a parallel RC circuit, with a nonlinear R.

Now, if you have a laser operating at some low (below-threshold) current level, and you then step up that current to turn on the laser, initially most of the added current will go to charging the "capacitor", and the laser won't lase until the charge reaches the threshold level. If the prior current level was lower, the initial charge on the capacitor would be lower, and so it would take longer for the new current to charge up the capacitor to threshold. This is why the laser turns on faster if the bias is higher.

Note: Above threshold, there is a gain-pinning effect (the gain is locked equal to the optical round-trip losses, and any extra current just goes to increasing the laser output power) so the laser no longer electrically behaves like a capacitor. Above threshold the laser is electrically very close to a short circuit (dependent on parasitic effects).